# Css Background with a transparent image and a gradient

Tags: html, css, image, background, gradient

How can I do it?
What I have is these image and these gradiente but i's only showing the gradient and not both.

```
div {
    background: url(/Icons/icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787);
}
```

Comment: try changing "background-image" to just "background"

Comment: I can't wait until we can stop using vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want multiple background images. Logically it may seem like a gradient is a background color, but browsers treat Gradient information like a background image.

Try something like:

```
div{
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787), url(/Icons/icon.png);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787), url(/Icons/icon.png);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787), url(/Icons/icon.png);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787), url(/Icons/icon.png);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a2a2a2, #878787), url(/Icons/icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is because gradients are defined as image values in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients